# How to Debug Common.js in Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-devtools, mediawiki

My MediaWiki:Common.js draws, and attaches an event to, a button.

```
$('#btnSave').html('<button>Send HTTP Post</button>');
```

How can i debug Common.js without first stepping through MW core code and jquery code?

I tried placing a `debugger;` flag in Common.js, but chrome didn't seem to notice it.

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnSave', function() { 
  debugger;
  $.ajax({
    url:"../api.php?action=edit&title=Portal:TagDescriptions&section=2&summary=Hello%20World",
    type:"POST",
    data:{ Text: "Hello, world.",
          token:"c30460d9159a5e2eccca60944ef286405b2393d1%2B%5C" },
    contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(data) {
        $('#lblDescription').html(data);
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: What is issue with your question, I cannot understand. can you explain it?

Comment: @KiranShahi  what part don't you understand?

Comment: put your debugger keyword inside ajax call!

Comment: @Sidhanshu_thx, i'll try that

Answer (score 1):

You may need to enable the "debug mode" of Resource Loader. This will disable the automatic script minification. That can easily be enabled by adding a `debug=true` parameter to the URL. [See explanation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader/Features#Debug_mode). This shouldn't be required, though.

This usually also forces the browser to get the latest modifications, which otherwise may be cached and could prevent you to see them in non-debug mode during a few minutes.

Caching may be the reason why the `debugger` statement does not work. Adding `debug=true` should prevent the caching problem.

Another problem may be a syntax error on your file preventing that code from executing, or a logic error causing the event not firing, maybe if the HTML element you're attaching the event to is not present on the page at the time the script gets executed. You should wrap the entire code inside a "document.ready" event. See [how to execute code on document.ready event with jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/). Example:

```
$(function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

Comment: Thx, i'll give it a try